# Android Unit Test with context failed on Travis CI with "java.lang.SecurityException" but Succeed locally since update Gradle 5.6

Tags: android, unit-testing, travis-ci, android-context, securityexception

All my tests used to run fine in Travis CI.
Since I have upgraded my project to gradle 5.6 some of my unit test failed on Travis CI but succeed locally.
They failed with the following message:

```
    java.lang.SecurityException
```

The test that failed are the one that need to have access to Android Context for small operation. I need to run them under a registration instrumentation but want to keep them as unit test.
I have tried `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)` and `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)`

For example this test that is testing a View Extension that allow me to change the visibility of my view

```
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.P])
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ViewExtUnitTest {

    private lateinit var context: Context

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<WatchMyBackApplication>()
    }

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun whenTrue_viewVisible(){
        val view = View(context)
        view.visibleOrInvisible(true)
        assertThat(view.visibility).isEqualTo(VISIBLE)

    }
}
```

It used to run fine locally and on Travis CI now it failed only on Travis CI

Here's my gradle configuration

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.60-eap-25'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.dicedmelon.gradle:jacoco-android:0.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }

    }
}
```